# SSRS and Comparison Operators on Numeric Portion of varchar

Tags: reporting-services, string-comparison, comparison-operators

Each returned transaction I am to report on is stored with a return reason code and a description of the return reason code. I built a tablix with two columns - one for return codes and another for descriptions. This works just peachy. The report owner is upset that a long list of codes will split pages - sigh. I was told to display them side-by-side.

I am new to t-sql and SSRS and its idiosyncrasies. I have minimal support from our DBAs. Two tables, filtered to display codes that meet a criteria sound simple enough.

My research:

MSDN's support network, Operators in Expressions page, and various help topics. I also found SO posts regarding split functions in t-sql and similar as well as one specifically asking about comparison and `varchar`. I found sites with helpful information like ResultData and Network Steve. I haven't found what I think I'm looking for.

My problem:

The return reason code is a `varchar` that *always* consists of the letter 'r' and two numeric digits (R00 to R99). It appears I can't run a comparison operator on an entire varchar that is alphanumeric; it doesn't recognize `IIF((Fields!... <= R17),True,False)`. Additionally, the company will not allow the warehouse or its functions to be edited so I cannot create my own.

My solution ideas:

- Add each R*nn* code to the tablix filter, individually. This means ~50 filters per tablix and seems a sloppy or inefficient way of handling this
- Separate the `varchar` string in to its alpha and numeric components and compare the latter using standard operators. This sounds the cleanest method but I'm unsure how to accomplish this in an expression or within SSRS
- Forgo the two-table idea and create one table with four columns (code, description, code, description). This still leaves me with how to set a limit on the number of rows that can be created before 'spilling over' to the other side

I appreciate being pointed to any resources or any offered input to the issue and my (not so?)logical approach to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your second option as follows:

`CInt(Fields!ReturnCode.Value.Substring(1,2))`

Comment: I feel silly I used every synonym but 'convert' in my search. Thank you. -- I took your suggestion and did some reading on it. I attempted to use: `=CInt(Fields!ReturnCode.Value.SubString(1,2))` in the filter expression. I set the item to `Integer`, used `<` for the operator, and `15` for the value. Running a report that will generate numbers below 15, the error it 'cannot evaluate the expression' is returned. Have I mis-used your suggestion or should I continue to look elsewhere for problems in my method?